# setInterval does not get invoked in fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

What causes the `setInterval` not to get invoked in `fadeOut`?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exercise</title>
    <style>
        #box {
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#box").fadeOut(3000, function () {
                setInterval("UpdateTime()", 100);
            });
        });

        function GetTime() {
            var now = new Date();
            var obj = {
                Hour: now.getHours(),
                Minute: now.getMinutes(),
                Second: now.getSeconds()
            };

            return obj;
        }

        function UpdateTime() {
            var box = $("#box");

            var obj = GetTime();
            if (obj.Hour < 10)
                obj.Hour = "0" + obj.Hour;
            if (obj.Minute < 10)
                obj.Minute = "0" + obj.Minute;
            if (obj.Second < 10)
                obj.Second = "0" + obj.Second;

            box.text(obj.Hour + ":" + obj.Minute + ":" + obj.Second);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(UpdateTime, 100);`

Comment: you are hiding the box using `fadeOut()` then who is displaying it back?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hee5um81/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hee5um81/2/

Comment: Think about the logic of your code. You fade out a div. That means the div is visually hidden. It doesn't matter if you change its contents, you **can't** see it. **Then**, you change its contents (every 100ms). Which is working just fine. But since the div is hidden, you can't see the changes. For example, something that makes sense: http://jsfiddle.net/5b0hp65a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `setInterval()` as the guys before suggested:

```
$("#box").fadeIn(3000, function () {
    setInterval(UpdateTime, 100);
});
```

And (if you want to diplay the time) change `.fadeOut()` to `.fadeIn()` (or remove fading completely).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cu3s5zwt/

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to use strings in setInterval. prefer to pass a function.

You can do it this way:

```
setInterval(UpdateTime, 100);
```

or if you need some arguments:

```
setInterval(function(){
    UpdateTime(argA, argB);
}, 100);
```

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood, why it doesn't work? UpdateTime was not call?

Comment: this is not the problem because `UpdateTime` is in the global scope

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood It **does** work, but so does your original code. You need to think about what's happening